# Copy/PasteSpecial for Multiple Worksheets to Single Workbook & Merge Ranges

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to copy the used range from each worksheet in one workbook, and paste only the values, transposed in a new workbook all on one sheet. If possible can they be stacked on top each other and not side by side? 
This is what I have tried so far..I'm not sure how to stack them and the paste special(transpose or paste values)isn't working properly. What am I doing wrong besides not know how to concatenate ranges? Not sure how much help the `application.union` method will be. 
Thanks for your help!

```
Sub transposeRange()
Dim sourceRange As Range, targetRange As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
     Set sourceRange = Workbooks("LBWPL_Jan_Feb.xlsm").Worksheets(1).UsedRange
    Set targetRange = Workbooks("janfeb_totals.xlsm").Worksheets(1).Range("A1")

        With sourceRange
            sourceRange.Copy
                targetRange.PasteSpecial _
                xlPasteValues, Transpose:=True 
 '   WorksheetFunction.Transpose (targetRange.Value2) << this seems to not execute.
        End With

    Next ws
End Sub
```

Now when I execute this code, I get the error that I cannot paste here because the copy and paste area are not the same size.

Comment: `sourceRange.Copy Destination:=targetRange`, `targetRange.PasteSpecial _`,
               `xlPasteValues _`,
                `Transpose:=True`... has a bunch of issues.

Comment: @BigBen Such as?..

Comment: Lol... first remove the `Destination:=targetRange`, otherwise the paste is happening twice.

Comment: You're missing the comma before `Transpose:=True`.

Comment: ^^^^ I was getting there :-)

Comment: @GSerg the comma goes on the same line or should I put the entire paste special on one line?

Comment: @BigBen what is the reason for removing the ```Destination:=targetRange``` ?

Comment: That means that you're pasting *twice*.... when you specify the `Destination`, then the paste happens immediately (w/o transposing). Omitting the `Destination` just copies to the clipboard, as noted in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.copy).

Comment: okay, I see. How should I modify the for statement to iterate through the sheets?

Comment: You probably should read up on loops. Currently your loop doesn't reference `ws` so will always act on the same sheet. Are you supposed to be looping through the sheets of "LBWPL_Jan_Feb.xlsm"?

Comment: @SJR yes I am. I see, I should change worksheets to ws

Comment: Well your `sourcerange` has to refer to each sheet in the loop and then you need to update the `targetrange` by finding the last used row rather than A1 each time.

Comment: @sjr for the ```targetrange``` part, could you use the range.offset property?

Comment: @BigBen, any more suggestions please?

Comment: What is the name of `ThisWorkbook`  ?

Comment: @TimWilliams the name is   LBWPL_Jan_Feb.xlsm

Comment: I'll add that I am no longer concerned with pasting the values. And the data is all values.

Comment: If I can only get each worksheet transposed into a new workbook that will be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like this should be a good start:

```
Sub transposeRange()
    Dim sourceRange As Range, targetRange As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet, data, rng As Range

    Set targetRange = Workbooks("janfeb_totals.xlsm").Worksheets(1).Range("A1")

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

        Set rng = ws.Range("A5").CurrentRegion  '<< edit
        data = Application.Transpose(rng.Value)

        targetRange.Resize(rng.Columns.Count, rng.Rows.Count).Value = data

        Set targetRange = targetRange.Offset(rng.Columns.Count) 'move destination down

    Next ws
End Sub
```

Comment: When I execute, I receive an out of memory error on the transpose line.

Comment: Do you have empty worksheets?  Or how much data do you have on the worksheet where it errors?  `UsedRange` is not the best way to get all of your data: if you know where it starts then you can use (eg) `Range("A1").CurrentRegion` to get all the data in a table starting at A1 (and having no blank columns or rows).

Comment: no empty worksheets. each sheet begins at A5. there are a few empty cells, but there isnt a full column or row that empty within the data table.

Comment: it was about 130 rows and at most 55 columns. However, replacing `.UsedRange` with `Range("A5").CurrentRegion` worked well and very fast. Thanks!